# Counterexample of $\mu$ completion of $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I've got a simple counterexample of the ability to $\mu$-complete any $\sigma$-algebra.  Not sure what the error in my logic is.  (I am attempting to prove Th 1.36 in Rudin Real and Complex Analysis)

Let (X, M, $\mu$) be the following measure space:

$$\begin{align}
X &= \{1, 2, 3\} \\
\mu(X) &= \infty \\
\mu(\{\}) &= 0 \\
\mu(\{1, 2\}) &= 1 \\
\mu(\{3\}) &= \infty
\end{align}$$

It can be verified that $M$ is closed under complement and countable union, and that $\mu$ is countably additive.

Now close this space.  There is only one pair of sets $A = \{3\}$ and $B = X$ with equal measure $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$.  This gives $\{\{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}\} \subset M^*$ and $\mu^*(\{1, 3\}) = \mu^*(\{2, 3\}) = \infty$.  Since $M^*$ must be closed under complement, we must have $\{\{1\}, \{2\}\} \subset M^*$ but neither of these is clamped between two sets in $M$ with equal measure.

Is the theorem false?

Comment: Rudin says $\mu(B-A)=0$. In your example, $\mu(B-A)=1$.

Comment: Oh, of course.  $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$ does not imply $\mu(B - A) = 0$!

Comment: I should retire from math and pick up another hobby.  If I can't read basic definitions, the world of math should be spared my carelessness.